# Question about UWP MediaPlaybackList events

Tags: uwp, cppwinrt

(**Update:** I suspect now this is a threading/race issue. When I create an event handler on the UI thread instead, I receive different results. I've edited my question to reflect this.)

I have a MediaPlaybackList populated with MediaPlaybackItems created from audio streams. All my MediaPlaybackItems consist of a single track. I'm interested in responding to when the current playback item changes. [The docs indicate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource#play-a-list-of-media-items-with-mediaplaybacklist) the right approach is to handle [MediaPlaybackList::CurrentItemChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplaybacklist.currentitemchanged?view=winrt-22000) events.

Here's my approach:

```cpp
// SomeClass.h
using namespace winrt::Windows::Media::Playback;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass();
    ...
    void OnPlaybackItemChanged(MediaPlaybackList const& sender,
                               CurrentMediaPlaybackItemChangedEventArgs const& args);
   ...
private:
    MediaPlayer m_MediaPlayer;
    MediaPlaybackList m_Playlist;
};

// SomeClass.cpp
SomeClass::SomeClass()
{
    m_Playlist.CurrentItemChanged({ this, &SomeClass::OnPlaybackItemChanged });
    m_MediaPlayer.Source(m_Playlist);
}
```

I append items to the playlist like so:

```cpp
MediaPlaybackItem item(MediaSource::CreateFromStream(stream, stream.ContentType()));
m_Playlist.Items().Append(item);
```

My event handlers create a local copy of the args parameter and then break so that I can inspect its value in the debugger:

```cpp
auto args_copy = args;
; // Breakpoint here
```

The streams play, and the CurrentItemChanged event fires. However, when I inspect the args.Reason() property from an event handler on the source thread, the only value I receive is InitialItem, apparently on each item change. Yet when I register a handler located on the UI thread, I receive a single InitialItem value, followed by EndOfStream values on each item change (which seems more in line with what one might expect).

For the life of me, I can't figure out why I'm getting different values passed to my event handlers depending on what thread they're on. The debugger is throwing no exceptions, and the event handlers are identical.

Questions:

1. Why might otherwise identical event handlers get different arguments depending on their thread?
2. At what points should I expect to see the different args.Reason() values? In particular, should there be an InitialItem event and a EndOfStream event for each item in the playlist? (I.e, does the "initial" of InitialItem refer to individual tracks inside the MediaPlaybackItems?)

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: In my view, this by design, when you process media element, you need keep them run in the ui thread,  or it will throw exception.  I think that's why it could not return correct args in the background-thread.

Comment: @CoCaIceDew You might be on to something. The debugger is indicating that my event handler is changing threads. This was never my intention in the first place, so I'm left with more questions now.

Comment: Can you try to run it in the UI thread manually with [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher?view=winrt-22000)?

Comment: @CoCaIceDew I get the same results. I'm just going to refactor things to circumvent the issue and leave this question open in the meantime. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Sure, it is better to report this problem with windows feed back hub, if the problem still exist.